# Rails form with same value on multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that uses a checkbox and a text area. When I go to submit the form it submits the value of the checkbox(1 or 0) and not the data from the text area. Below is my form.

```
        <%= form_for(:add_kids) do |kid|%>
                <div class="kidsname">
                    <%= kid.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First", class: "name" %>
                    <%= kid.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last", class: "name" %>
                </div>
            <br>
                <div class="allergens">
                <h4>Allergens/Asthma:</h4>
                    <div class="allergens-list">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <%= kid.check_box :soy %>
                                <%= kid.label :soy %>
                                <%= kid.check_box :peanuts %>
                                <%= kid.label :peanuts %>
                                <%= kid.check_box :wheat %>
                                <%= kid.label :wheat %>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <%= kid.check_box :milk %>
                                <%= kid.label :milk %>
                                <%= kid.check_box :nuts %>
                                <%= kid.label :nuts, "Tree Nuts" %>
                                <%= kid.check_box :eggs %>
                                <%= kid.label :eggs %>
                            </li>
                            <li class="otherNeeds">
                                <%= kid.check_box :other, {class: "other"} %>
                                <%= kid.label :other, "Other Needs" %>
                                <div class="concernsContainer">
                                    <h3>Please type your kid's needs or concerns</h3>
                                    <div class="concernsBox">
                                        <%= kid.text_area :other, placeholder: "Type here...", maxlength: 500, disabled: 'disabled' %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: There is no question here, only a statement...

Comment: Why is the textarea disabled?

Comment: It is disabled until a jQuery onclick event. The question is, why is it writing the value from the checkbox and not from the textarea? Thank You

Comment: Hesham, it seems that the disable is what is causing the issue. Thanks for asking the question that helped me find the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You have both check_box and textarea related to the same attribute - `:other`
The attributes are passed to rails app based on the attribute `name` of your controls, so if you check the name of textarea and the name of checkbox, you'll find they are the same.

I assume you want to get both attributes, so you need to specify different names there. And anyway, more details about what exactly you want to get in the `params` would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the form_for api syntax ?

```
<%= form_for :person do |f| %>
  First name: <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
  Last name : <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br />
  Biography : <%= f.text_area :biography %><br />
  Admin?    : <%= f.check_box :admin %><br />
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```